# UIImagePickerController: Custom camera overlay sitting on top of default controls?

Tags: ios4, camera, uipickerviewcontroller

I'm creating a custom camera UI using `UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayView` property. However, I'd like to keep some of the existing UI -- specifically the flash and camera selection buttons at the top.

My thought was that I'd keep `showsCameraControls = YES` set the `cameraOverlayView` to my custom UI and then use `[picker.view bringSubviewToFront:overlayView]` to make sure my controls on the bottom are sitting on top of the default controls.

Alas, this does not work. I've tried moving the overlay to the front of the view hierarchy in various places without luck. **Is there any `UIImagePickerController` hackery that could achive this?** It seems a shame not to be able to reuse at least some of the camera controls while still customizing the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further investigation it appears this is not possible. You either have to use all of the default cameara UI or none of it.

Comment: I haven't seen anything that has changed in recent releases.

Comment: i have not tried this yet, but the apple docs state that this is possible: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView here is the paragraph: " If you have the default camera controls set to be visible, incorporate transparency into your view, or position it to avoid obscuring the underlying content."