# take picture method on cameraOverlayView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, custom-view

My problem;
Hide the default camera controls and overlay it with my my own. This is made with the property cameraOverlayView. I also was having problem triggering the takePicture method.

Comment: Just go ahead and try something. Come back here if you run into concrete problems.

Comment: http://jcuz.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/pickerfocus/

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController: Custom camera overlay sitting on top of default controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251336/uiimagepickercontroller-custom-camera-overlay-sitting-on-top-of-default-control)

Comment: This is actually the tutorial that my project is based on. But it doesn't mention anything about the takepicture method... Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

(Question solved in the comments and in the edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Here is what came to be the solution:
>
> I have two UIViewController. The main ViewController and the CustomOverlay (for the camera controls).
>
> I the ViewController I declare the source type and the overlay for may camera control like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // notification from the CustomOverlay Controller that triggers the eTakePicture method
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(eTakePicture:) name:@"eTakePicture" object:nil];

    daysBtn.delegate = self;
    daysBtn.hidden = YES;

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    picker.delegate = self;

    overlay = [[CustomOverlay alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomOverlay" bundle:nil];
    // Overlay for the camera controls, note the "= overlay.view", the ".view" was important
    // because the overlay is a new UIViewcontroller (with xib) so you have to call the
    // view. Most tutorials that I saw were based on UIView so only "= overlay" worked.
    picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

> Now on the CustomOverlay, which is a UIViewController I have the take picture button and want this button to trigger a method in the main ViewController:

```
- (IBAction)shoot:(id)control {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"eTakePicture" object:self];

}
```

> And back to the main ViewController:

```
-(void)eTakePicture:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [picker takePicture];
}
```

> All the code above will change a little more once I review it, specially the first block where I have to have a condition to check if cameraSourceType is available.
>
> Hope that helps somebody out there. Any question, just ask.